# SQL query for joining one or another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables TableA and TableB with some data:

```
IDA|TDATA   IDB|TDATA
---+-----   ---+-----
 1 | A1      1 | B1
 2 | A2      2 | B2
```

and one central table:

```
ID|TID|TAB|CDATA
--+---+---+-----
10| 1 | A | C1
11| 2 | B | C2
12| 2 | A | C3
```

Data from central table should be joined with data from TableA or TableB (joining columns TID and TAB). TID is reference to ID in joined table IDA or IDB and column TAB defines which table should be joined. So the final result from query should look like:

```
ID|TDATA|CDATA
--+-----+-----
10| A1  | C1
11| B2  | C2
13| A2  | C3
```

How this SQL query should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
SELECT c.id,
       coalesce( a.tdata, b.tdata ) tdata,
       c.cdata
  FROM central_table c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA a
         ON( c.tid = a.ida AND
             c.tab = 'A' )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB b
         ON( c.tid = b.idb AND
             c.tab = 'B' )
```

I would seriously question the data model here, however.  If you don't know whether a column in C references a column in A or B, something is generally incorrect in the data model.  Fixing the data model will make this (and all your other queries, most likely) much easier to write and much easier to optimize.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I completely agree with you that this is not good database modeling practice, but it happens sometime that one has one code (lookup) table for more other tables instead of many small code tables.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is TAB followed by TID, then the following will work:

```
SELECT ID, CONCAT(TAB, CAST(TID AS CHAR[2])) AS TDATA, CDATA FROM CentralTable;
```

If the table names are constant (e.g., nothing other than A or B will be in there), then you can do:

```
(SELECT ID, TDATA, CDATA FROM CentralTable a
    JOIN TableA b ON (a.ID = b.IDA) WHERE a.TAB = 'A')
UNION ALL
(SELECT ID, TDATA, CDATA FROM CentralTable a
    JOIN TableB b ON (a.ID = b.IDB) WHERE a.TAB = 'B')
```